# Telemetry Antenna

Tags: wireless, antenna, xbee

I am developing a telemetry system for a solar car. I am going to be using xbee chips to communicate from the base-station/chase-car to the solar car. The xbee chips are 900MHZ, or 2.4ghz. I am thinking about using high gain omnidirectional antennas on both ends, with lengths about 3.6ft, and a gain of 15DB. I need to be able to reliably transmit data line of sight from 2 miles away.

Do you think this will work? Should I go with the 900mhz or 2.4ghz xbee?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where will you be driving and what's the terrain like? Antenna gain is normally specified in dBi or dBd and it makes a difference. Collinear antennas have about the best gain but I've never seen high gain omnidirectional antennas greater than 12 dBi at these frequencies. If you could post links to your modules and antennas, that would help in determining if your proposed setup is feasible. The choice between 900/2400 MHz will depend on what's around you. Open desert is flat and the chances for lots of WiFi is rather slim. Not sure what's used at 900, that band of frequencies was used by cordle

Comment: 2 miles in what terrain(hilly or perfectly flat), what elevation over the terrain are you expecting, are you the only one at 900MHz(i doubt this), what are the output powers of the xigbee modules you are discussing, what are the receiver sensitivities and can you give us links to their datasheets?

Comment: Does your solar car need to be legal? Although lots of people build range-boosting WiFi antennas, many of them illegally violate the transmitting power limits for unlicensed ISBM (900/2.4/5.7) transmission in the US. This may be an issue if your car enters a competition or is intended for production.

Comment: The terrain where we will need the 2 mile range is perfectly flat on a bright and sunny day. And yes it needs to be street legal. I have investigated, and found that a 4.8ft omnidirectional antenna, along with a high power xbee module will work. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) radios, even the higher power XBee-Pro which has a maximum power output of +18 dBm (North America only), will be able to reliably communicate over a 2 mile link in all conditions.

One of the XBee modules with "long range" capability is the [XStream](http://www.digi.com/pdf/ds_xstreammodule.pdf) which claims:

> Indoor/Urban range up to 1500 feet (900 MHz model) Outdoor
>   line-of-site range up to 20 miles (with high gain antenna)

Now it is probably safe to assume that actual results in the field will not be substantially better than the claims being made by the manufacturer, and the above ranges are under ideal conditions. Assuming there will be times when your car will be driving in less than ideal conditions, such as an urban area, there will be times when their urban range of 1500 feet may be much closer to what you observe than 2 miles.

When designing a data link between your cars the best way to start is not with the radios themselves but rather with a [link budget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_budget) analysis.

> A link budget is the accounting of all of the gains and losses from
>   the transmitter, through the medium (free space, cable, waveguide,
>   fiber, etc.) to the receiver in a telecommunication system. It
>   accounts for the attenuation of the transmitted signal due to
>   propagation, as well as the antenna gains, feedline and miscellaneous
>   losses. Randomly varying channel gains such as fading are taken into
>   account by adding some margin depending on the anticipated severity of
>   its effects. The amount of margin required can be reduced by the use
>   of mitigating techniques such as antenna diversity or frequency
>   hopping.
>
> A simple link budget equation looks like this:
>
> ```
> Received Power (dBm) = Transmitted Power (dBm) + Gains (dB) − Losses (dB)
> ```

For a data channel you will also need to determine what is the required [capacity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_capacity) ( do you need 10 MBits per second or is 300 BAUD OK?) and  an acceptable [bit error rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_error_rate). In other words there will be times when data gets garbled in transmission and you need to deal with this either by re-transmission, redundant transmissions, check digits or some such means.

Here is an Intersil [Tutorial on Basic Link Budget Analysis](http://www.sss-mag.com/pdf/an9804.pdf).

Bringing this back to what is expedient, the easiest solution would be to simply use higher power radios, if possible. You do not say if this is a school, for profit company or what. Educational projects often use ham radios, specifically [APRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Packet_Reporting_System) for projects like this.

ADDENDUM: One alternative you might like to investigate is TI's [CC1120 development kit](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/analog/sub_1_GHz_performance_line_rf_ic/index.shtml);

TI claims "More than 10 km out-of-the-box with development kit (139-dB link budget) and 65-dB adjacent channel rejection"

Comment: We opted for the xtend from digi, with a claim to a 40 mile range. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Reid - be sure and let us know how it works out for you.

Comment: Will do. The parts are on order, and I should be able to get the system up and running in a few weeks. Thank you for your help!!! By the way we are designing a RF analog backup telemetry system.

Answer (score 2):

Last year we have used similar system for solar car races. 15dbi antenna (connected to an access point) in the middle of the race track, 7dbi antenna on car, 4dbi in PIT. We reduced access point's data transter rate to 1 mbit. It worked OK.

[Access Point](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=292)

[Center Antenna](http://gnswireless.com/GNS1456_15dbi_Omni_Antenna.htm)

[Car Antenna](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=416)

[Race Track](http://izmirulkuyarispisti.com/Flashes/Image/pist.JPG)

Network protocol tracks the error, using hash algorithm and package IDs.
Sync -> Control -> ID -> Message -> Error Check -> End of Message.

The message is sent with an error code. And reciever takes the message and error code. It processes the same hash algorithm, and produces a new error code. It compares 2 error codes. If they are not same, it sends the package ID to the transmitter, and wants the package again.

You might want to be participate in World Solar Challange. And short range communication may not be the best option. GPRS should be in the box.

I hope it helps. I wish you luck in the race =)

Edit:
Here is an example software design. It is called Strategy Pattern. You can change communication easily even at runtime. Electronics guys usualy don't use Object Oriented Software Princibles. You can achieve same behavior without OOP. But as a software developer, I prefer that way.
Design Patterns remembering tip: While playing a shooter game, you change your weapon depends on situations (like distance). It is your game "strategy".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class ISendable
{
    public:
        virtual void Send(std::string data) {};
};
class Network: public ISendable
{
    public:
        void Send(std::string data)
        { std::cout<<"Send over Network: "<<data<<std::endl; }
};
class GPRS: public ISendable
{
    public:
        void Send(std::string data)
        { std::cout<<"Send over GPRS: "<<data<<std::endl; }
};
class Car
{
    public:
        Car() { sendBehavior = new Network(); }
        void Send(std::string data)
        { sendBehavior->Send(data); }
        void ChangeCommunication(ISendable *communicationType)
        { sendBehavior = communicationType; }
    private:
        ISendable *sendBehavior;
};
int main()
{
    Car *c = new Car();
    c->Send("data 1");
    c->ChangeCommunication(new GPRS());
    c->Send("data 2");
}
```

Output:

Send over Network: data 1

Send over GPRS: data 2

Comment: We will be participating in the World Solar Challange, could you elaborate more on GPRS, and how we could use it?

Comment: The easy way may be using a module with serial interface. You can send AT commands to the modem and select the communication type like TCP, and connect spesific IP and Port. Data traffic should be low because of charges. But you can track your car wherever you want. You also may need a static IP or a server. You can design your sofware, to change communication type and the rest of the code stays what it is.
Here is a easy module with some explanation:
http://www.libelium.com/squidbee/index.php?title=New_GPRS_module_for_Arduino_(Hilo_-_Sagem)

Comment: We have talked it over, and we are going to use xtreme wireless modules from digi. These seem like the best bet, and they dont need to be accompanied by a data plan.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of considerations about choosing the antenna (the shape, not the power, since Jonny has already covered this topic).

You don't need an omnidirectional antenna, but eventually only in the horizontal plane; so if you can achieve a good vertical directionality (check for broadside antennas, like the ones used in radio transmission) you save a lot of power, and that means higher range within the legal limits.

[image: From Balanis III]

*This is the radiation diagram od a broadside array*

Then you can make another consideration: is the base station in the center of the track, or in one side? If you are in the second case, you can suppress the radiation behind the antenna (outside the track) with a screen: again, you would save a lot of power (the system becomes more directive) and avoid transmitting where is not needed.

Comment: Well for the most part, it is off centered, but still in the center. We are also going to be using this setup while on the road, when the chase car can be just about anywhere in relation to the solar car. This is why we need the omnidirectional antenna.

Comment: @Reid so you cango for the first solution, but keep in mind that a simple dipole antenna irradiate a lot of power "upside" and "downside" (diagonally); this power is wasted in your case, because the car is likely to be in a flat surface.